# Gmail query working in Gmail search but not with the API call

Tags: gmail-api

I have the following query to search for messages from a specific email address and with specific word/words in the subject.

```
from:noreply@kp.com AND subject:forgot
```

The above query works and returns 1 message when I use it in the Gmail's search box but it doesn't work and returns no messages with the following Request URI on OAuth 2.0 Playground:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=subject:lsp AND from:noreply@kp.com
```

The Response is as follows:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong in the syntax of the Request URI for the "AND" condition? Because the following work without the "AND":

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=subject:lsp

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from:noreply@kp.com
```

Can you please help me with the correct Syntax for the "AND" condition? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error in the syntax, the correct syntax for different filter conditions is to use a comma , between different filter conditions to separate them as follows:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=subject:lsp, from:noreply@kp.com
```